# How to expand the text-width with CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in programming and I am designing my blog with Python Flask, CSS and Bootstrap as first project. I am struggling a bit with the design of the post section. This is what I was able to do:
[image]

As you can see, the text is too much in the center. How can I expand a bit the text to the right and to the left, so that it appears more readable? I tried with the Bootstrap grid-system but I could not reach any results. The problem is also that the Facebook-plugin is quite unflexible, so I have to adapt it in any case to the text-width. This is my code-snippet:

```
<article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        {{ post.content|safe }}
        <hr>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v9.0" nonce="I8QQqnPj"></script>
      <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" data-numposts="5" data-width="400"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Thank you very much for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your column to the max width: `<div class="col-12"</div>`, or you can use `<div class="container-fluid"</div>` for a full width container, instead of the "container".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. Actually it was pretty easy. I just expanded the number of the column: `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-10 mx-auto">`. This is how it looks now:

[image]